# How to sftp a file to a mainframe

Tags: linux, sftp, mainframe

This is my first time to sftp a file from linux to mainframe. I am using the following command.

```
/somedirectory>sftp PR0010@someserver
Connecting to someserver...
someuser@someuser's password: 
sftp> put –a SOME.FILE.1111 –o “'SOME.FILE.1111(0)'”
sftp> ls
```

And though I manage to copy the file successfully to mainframe, however mainframe can't see it.

By the way, if I use FTP to do the transfer, its completely fine and can be seen by the mainframe.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you use -o?

Comment: What OS is the mainframe running?

Comment: sftp copies files via ssh, so likely the file ended up in your Unix System Services (USS) file system. Login with ssh to see where your home directory etc. is. The ftp server on the mainframe OTOH uses the "main" file systen.

Comment: Is the mainframe using the Co:Z sftp server from Dovetailed Technologies?  There are specific options for GDGs in cozsftp.

Comment: What are the ftp clients your using?  That will make a difference in the behaviour.